# Custom action on failed user login

Tags: windows, authentication

Is it possible to run custom action (e.g. run some script) on failed login attempt in windows? I'm thinking about .NET application that would send messages if someone would try to access my laptop but I really don't know where to start...

Comment: don't think it can be done. Alternate solutions: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081660/disable-account-due-to-login-3-times-failed?rq=1

Comment: I'm more interested in extending Windows login mechanism. But if that can't be done then I pass...